# Which remote communication protocols can't be restricted by Network Security Configuration?

Tags: android, network-security, android-network-security-config

In Android app can completely opt-out from using cleartext
protocols, such as HTTP, FTP, IMAP, SMTP, WebSockets or
XMPP. But are there any protocols that don't affected by this and can send data to remote server?

Comment: You dont have to opt-out from http protocol as it is blocked by default. FTP is not blocked by default. Please rewrite your post.

Comment: @blackapps, where you see keyword 'default' in my question? I'm using word 'can' meaning possibility to block.